# C# How to pause Form1 while Form2 is active?

Tags: c#, forms, sleep, pause

As the title says; that's all I need. I have 2 forms : **Form1** and **Form2**. At some point of my code I want to do `Form2.ShowDialog()` and after Form2 is closed I want to resume Form1. How can i do this?

I tried using `Thread.Sleep(sometime)` but this will just disable any controls,timers, etc from Form1 and resume after the period passed. The problem is that I cant know how much time it will take for my user to press something in Form2.

Comment: Just hide Form1 while Form2 is active, or start Form2 modal.

Comment: Once Form2 is closed, Form1 should resume operations as normal, if you use `ShowDialog()`...

Comment: Include the code you are trying as to see where's the mistake.

Comment: `Form2.ShowDialog` will make `Form1` "unreachable" to the user until it is closed. I do not see the issue or behavior you want?

Comment: `Form1` is not running, it is waiting for input and doing nothing, so you do not have to pause it.

Comment: Thanks it works lol ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per KDecker mentioned in a comment to your question:

If you want to show something Modally (that is the form behind is unusable) use the `ShowDialog()` method. This will make it so you can only use the form that `ShowDialog()` was called on.

If you want to show it Modeless, then just use the `Show()` method on Form. This will make it so you can use both forms

See the MSDN documentation for reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(v=vs.71).aspx